# Converting a singular integral into a non-singular integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, singular-integrals

The integral I am working with is $$\int_0^{50 \pi/180} (\cos(x)-\cos(50\pi/180))^{-1/2} dx$$
I am trying to convert this singular integral to a non-singular integral.
Is there a way to change the variable to make this non- singular so I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a = 50 \pi/180$ is the upper endpoint of the integral,

$$ \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{\cos(x) - \cos(a)}{x - a} = \cos'(a) = -\sin(a) \ne 0$$
so the integrand goes to infinity as $x \to a-$, but only like $(x-a)^{-1/2}$ which is integrable.  This suggests the change of variables
$a - x  = t^2$
which makes the integral into
$$ \int_0^{\sqrt{a}} \dfrac{t\; dt}{\sqrt{\cos(a-t^2) - \cos(a)}}$$

BTW, your integral has a "closed form" expression in terms of elliptic integrals.  In Maple's notation (which follows Gradshteyn and Ryzhik), it is

$$ \sqrt {2}{\it EllipticF} \left( 2\,{\frac {\cos \left( {\frac {13\,\pi
}{36}} \right) }{\sqrt {-2\,\cos \left( {\frac {5\,\pi}{18}} \right) +
2}}},1/2\,\sqrt {-2\,\cos \left( {\frac {5\,\pi}{18}} \right) +2}
 \right) 
$$
where $EllipticF$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: What about when t=0 and then we are left with cos(a)-cos(a) in the denominator?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something because isn't this integral still singular when t=0?

Comment: Well, that's the point: the denominator is on the order of $t$, but that $t$ in the numerator makes the singularity removable.

Comment: My fault, I meant to say, how we can make this integral non-singular?

Comment: I am trying to rewrite this integral so I can evaluate it

Comment: My rewriting **is** non-singular (if you take the integrand's value at $0$ to be $-1/\sqrt{\sin(a)}$ which is its limit as $t \to 0+$).

Comment: Maybe you have a different notion of "non-singular".  How would you define "non-singular"?